# tsql alias for select generated column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, alias

In T-SQL, I need to assign an alias name to a calculated value for using it in a CASE clause.

```
SELECT
    RUT,
    (11 - ((SUBSTRING(RUT, 1, 1) * 3
            + SUBSTRING(RUT, 2, 1) * 2
            + SUBSTRING(RUT, 3, 1) * 7
            + SUBSTRING(RUT, 4, 1) * 6
            + SUBSTRING(RUT, 5, 1) * 5
            + SUBSTRING(RUT, 6, 1) * 4
            + SUBSTRING(RUT, 7, 1) * 3
            + SUBSTRING(RUT, 8, 1) * 2) % 11)) AS VerifDigit,
    CASE
       WHEN VerifDigit = 10 THEN 'K'
       WHEN VerifDigit = 11 THEN '0'
       ELSE VerifDigit
    END
FROM  
    Citizen
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use CROSS APPLY with VALUES to calculate the result and then refer to that value in your CASE statement e.g. ...

```
SELECT
    RUT,
    xa.VerifDigit,
    CASE
       WHEN xa.VerifDigit = '10' THEN 'K'
       WHEN xa.VerifDigit = '11' THEN '0' -- this will never occur
       ELSE xa.VerifDigit
   END
FROM  
    Citizen
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(cast((11 - (( substring(RUT, 1, 1) * 3
                            + SUBSTRING(RUT, 2, 1) * 2
                            + SUBSTRING(RUT, 3, 1) * 7
                            + SUBSTRING(RUT, 4, 1) * 6
                            + SUBSTRING(RUT, 5, 1) * 5
                            + SUBSTRING(RUT, 6, 1) * 4
                            + SUBSTRING(RUT, 7, 1) * 3
                            + SUBSTRING(RUT, 8, 1) * 2) % 11))  
                    AS char(2)))) xa(VerifDigit)
```

A couple of things worth pointing out though...

1. You will need to cast the result (VerifDigit) to a character datatype if you are replacing it with 'K' otherwise the CASE will fail with a data conversion; this is shown in the example.
2. The result of Modulo (%) 11 will never be 11; the remainder of anything divided by 11 will be between 0 and 10, so the second CASE/WHEN will **never** be hit.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an alias in a select clause in which it was defined.  One workaround here would be to subquery, e.g.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        RUT,(11 - ((SUBSTRING(RUT,1,1)*3
        + SUBSTRING(RUT,2,1)*2
        + SUBSTRING(RUT,3,1)*7
        + SUBSTRING(RUT,4,1)*6
        + SUBSTRING(RUT,5,1)*5
        + SUBSTRING(RUT,6,1)*4
        + SUBSTRING(RUT,7,1)*3
        + SUBSTRING(RUT,8,1)*2)%11)) AS VerifDigit
    FROM Citizen
)

SELECT
    VerifDigit,
    CASE
        WHEN VerifDigit = 10 THEN 'K'
        WHEN VerifDigit = 11 THEN '0'
        ELSE VerifDigit
    END
FROM cte;
```